# Reading pcap files and fetch dport number with specific ip address

Tags: python-3.x, wireshark, scapy, packet, pcap

I'm new to Python. I'm reading pcap file using scapy, i want to fetch dport number by specifying particular ip addresses, I have something like below

```
from scapy.all import *
pkts = rdpcap('example.pcap')


for pkt in pkts:
    if IP in pkt:
        ip_src=pkt[IP].src
        ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
    if TCP in pkt:
        tcp_sport=pkt[TCP].sport
        tcp_dport=pkt[TCP].dport
        print " IP src " + str(ip_src) + " TCP sport " + str(tcp_sport) 
        print " IP dst " + str(ip_dst) + " TCP dport " + str(tcp_dport)
        if ( ( pkt[IP].src == "10.116.206.114") or ( pkt[IP].dst == "10.236.138.184") ):
            print("!")
```

pcap file

[image]

required output

[image]

here in the above code i'm getting both results as shown below

```
IP src 10.116.206.114 TCP dport 443
IP dst 10.236.138.184 TCP dport 443
----
IP src 10.236.138.184 TCP dport 12516
IP dst 10.116.206.114 TCP dport 12516
.
.
```

so on, but i want only with specific src and dst ip which i specify like below i dont want both dport numbers.

```
IP src 10.116.206.114 TCP dport 443
IP dst 10.236.138.184 TCP dport 443
----
IP src 10.116.206.114 TCP dport 22
IP dst 10.236.138.184 TCP dport 22
```

Please suggest a method and explain how to fetch dport number from specific ip address. Thank you!

Comment: Voting to close as it's more regarding finding a [library](https://pypi.org/project/python-libpcap/) to read pacaps rather than how to solve a particular problem.

Comment: i edited the script please check once @Torxed

Comment: And what's not working? (Also, I fixed an indentation issue with `print("!")` as it seamed to have jumped out of your if-block. But please elaborate what isn't working, because it looks like you've correctly accessed all the information you need except for the `Protocol` part. But there's still nothing wrong in the question.

Comment: See in my code its giving out both the src and dst with ip addreses and vise versa but i need only one which i specify and thanks for the info @Torxed